# Spring Security and DB authorization

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-security, authorization

I have a problem with login. If my username and password same , login is success but if username and password different, I have error `Reason: Bad credentials`

This is configure method in Configuration Security class:

```
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
    auth
    .jdbcAuthentication()
    .dataSource(dataSource)
    .usersByUsernameQuery("select username,password, enabled from users where username=? ")
    .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select u.username, r.name from users u, security_role r, users_security_role uhr where u.id_user = uhr.id and r.id = uhr.security_role_id and u.username =?");
}
```

I have tabe in DB users where username and password.
If I insert user in database , like `"user","user"` or `"usernameandpasswordsame","usernameandpasswordsame"` everything works , and I can login and get correct user_role, but if insert user in database with username and password different , like `"user","userpass"` , I have error.

Here is also another configure method in same configuration security class:

```
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http.csrf().disable()
         .authorizeRequests()
            .expressionHandler(webExpressionHandler())
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
         .formLogin()
            .and()
         .logout()
         .deleteCookies("remove")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
         .permitAll();
    }
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong or problem?

Comment: I could not reproduce your problem. Please check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I guess that you made a mistake somewhere and filled the password-variable with the username-value. Your queries look correct, so I would check the frontend (jsp, ....) and make sure that the variables are not mixed.

Answer (score 0):

The only case where this would happen is if you are saving the username field of your form to the password column. Try directly inserting your username and password into your table. If you are using H2 check your SQL files.